# production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-8, I deleted .env when I'm about to deploy to production.

In the .env, I have:

> APP_KEY=base64:JMKPPddG+sPK/ufZKNGwGTStKbMLO2Vnv/4i2fA3j1c=

and config/app:

> 'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

Everything was working fine until when I deleted .env

When I run the application, I got this error:

> production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified in Laravel

I don't want to use .env

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Comment: "_I don't want to use .env_" Why not? What's wrong with using `.env`? What else do you want to use then?

Comment: @brombeer - I'm considering security issue. My DB name and Password can be detected there

Comment: @user11352561 Your server is going to have to have the database credentials *somewhere* Laravel can get to them. `.env` is the standard way. Properly configured, this file is not accessible to anyone without shell access to the server.

Comment: I think that's _why_ `.env` exists. It's outside of your server's public folder, so if anyone _can_ get access to read your `.env` file you have far more serious security problems. [Environment File Security](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#environment-file-security) might be worth a read

Comment: If you don't want to use `.env` you can do `'key' => "base64:JMKPPddG+sPK/ufZKNGwGTStKbMLO2Vnv/4i2fA3j1c="` but this means hardcoding your app key in your source files which is significantly worse than using `.env`

Answer (score 0):

first run this command to cache configurations:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

then u can remove .env

note: calling env() helper from your code will always return null because .env values can be accessed only from config files.
blocking access to .env file in the server is a better solution though.